# 'SDL_main' : must return a value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

I am trying to retreive content of websice in c++ usind SDL but it is giving me this error:

> 'SDL_main' : must return a value

my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_net.h"
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDLNet_Init();

    IPaddress ip;
    SDLNet_ResolveHost(&ip,"www.linux.org",80);

    const char* http="GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.linux.org\n\n";

    TCPsocket client=SDLNet_TCP_Open(&ip);

    SDLNet_TCP_Send(client,http,strlen(http)+1);

    char text[10000];

    while(SDLNet_TCP_Recv(client,text,10000))
        std::cout << text;

    SDLNet_TCP_Close(client);

    SDLNet_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

When I put return 0; at the end, it built project but it finished immediately after that
(I am using vs2012)

**UPDATE**

```
cout<<"Some message";
```

doesn't print anything, is it possible that I have configured my imports wrong? are those additional dependencies right?

> SDL.lib;SDL_net.lib;SDLmain.lib

I don't know what else could be wrong ...

Answer (score 6):

It's because SDL defines a macro like this:

```
#define main SDL_main
```

So the function you've written is actually called `SDL_main` and like any other function that is not the actual `main` function, if it doesn't return `void`, you have to give it a `return` statement.

Comment: But why did it end right after it built it when I put return 0 at the end?

Comment: Sorry not I am confused, what should I return then?

Comment: You do NOT need to return anything from main. It must be declared to return an int but if you miss out a return statement then return 0 is implied. (This is *only* for main)

Answer (score 0):

because your code doesn't loop forever it just returns 0 after first pass, you need to make a loop like:

```
while(1){
sdl_events event;    

switch(event){
//handle events, drawings and so on
...
...
...
case SDL_QUIT:
 exit (0);
 break;
}

}
```

http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/OpenGL_Full_Example

**UPDATE**
you may also have some problem connecting to host so you could check if connection succeed like this:

```
#define MAXLEN 1024
int result;
char msg[MAXLEN];

result = SDLNet_TCP_Recv(sock,msg,MAXLEN-1);
if(result <= 0) {
    // TCP Connection is broken. (because of error or closure)
    SDLNet_TCP_Close(sock);
    exit(1);
}
else {
    msg[result] = 0;
    printf("Received: \"%s\"\n",msg);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
change this:

```
while(SDLNet_TCP_Recv(client,text,10000))
        std::cout << text;
```

to this:

```
while(SDLNet_TCP_Recv(client,text,9999))
        std::cout << text;
```

**UPDATE 3**
try this, put your receive part in this if statement

```
if(SDLNet_SocketReady(client) == 1)
{
  while(SDLNet_TCP_Recv(client,text,9999))
       std::cout << text;
}
```

if this still doesn't work I suggest to use QT sockets or Boost asio, both async and more intuitive

Comment: Please clarify your answer, what part of the question are you refering to.

Comment: your code is fine just need to wrap it in a while loop that loops forever, than you can create an event(by pressing the exit button on keyboard or something) and handle that event to exit the while loop(by returning 0 or using exit(0)), this way your program will keep on running(until you press the exit button) and you remove the compiler error

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still not working, I've just found out that this
cout<<"Some message";
doesn't print anything, is it possible that I have configured my imports wrong? are those additional dependencies right? SDL.lib;SDL_net.lib;SDLmain.lib

I don't know what else could be wrong